# Dask ValueError: Schema different

Tags: dask, parquet, pyarrow

My question is very close to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439245/dask-dataframe-read-parquet-schema-difference) :

I converted an csv file into parquet using 'pyarrow' engine. 
I got a schema error when I read the file. Unlike the previous question, it seems like some parquet file has added new column that is not in the original file.

```py
ddf = dd.read_parquet('snappywork',
                      columns = colnames
                      )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\gunsu.son\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet.py", line 1397, in read_parquet
    infer_divisions=infer_divisions,
  File "C:\Users\gunsu.son\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet.py", line 828, in _read_pyarrow
    paths, filesystem=get_pyarrow_filesystem(fs), filters=filters
  File "C:\Users\gunsu.son\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py", line 1008, in __init__
    self.validate_schemas()
  File "C:\Users\gunsu.son\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\parquet.py", line 1061, in validate_schemas
    dataset_schema))
ValueError: Schema in snappywork\part.129.parquet was different. 
id: string
link_id: string
parent_id: string
body: string
author: string
score: string
subreddit: string
stickied: bool
created_time: string
__index_level_0__: string
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "column_indexes": [{"na'
            b'me": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_'
            b'type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns":'
            b' [{"name": "id", "field_name": "id", "pandas_type": "unicode", "'
            b'numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "link_id", "f'
            b'ield_name": "link_id", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "'
            b'object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "parent_id", "field_name": '
            b'"parent_id", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "'
            b'metadata": null}, {"name": "body", "field_name": "body", "pandas'
            b'_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"'
            b'name": "author", "field_name": "author", "pandas_type": "unicode'
            b'", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "score", '
            b'"field_name": "score", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "'
            b'object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "subreddit", "field_name": '
            b'"subreddit", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "'
            b'metadata": null}, {"name": "stickied", "field_name": "stickied",'
            b' "pandas_type": "bool", "numpy_type": "bool", "metadata": null},'
            b' {"name": "created_time", "field_name": "created_time", "pandas_'
            b'type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"n'
            b'ame": null, "field_name": "__index_level_0__", "pandas_type": "u'
            b'nicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}], "creator": '
            b'{"library": "pyarrow", "version": "0.14.0"}, "pandas_version": "'
            b'0.25.0"}'}
vs
id: string
link_id: string
parent_id: string
body: string
author: string
score: string
subreddit: string
stickied: bool
created_time: string
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "'
            b'stop": 248538, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "f'
            b'ield_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "objec'
            b't", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "i'
            b'd", "field_name": "id", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": '
            b'"object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "link_id", "field_name": "'
            b'link_id", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "met'
            b'adata": null}, {"name": "parent_id", "field_name": "parent_id", '
            b'"pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": nu'
            b'll}, {"name": "body", "field_name": "body", "pandas_type": "unic'
            b'ode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "autho'
            b'r", "field_name": "author", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_typ'
            b'e": "object", "metadata": null}, {"name": "score", "field_name":'
            b' "score", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "met'
            b'adata": null}, {"name": "subreddit", "field_name": "subreddit", '
            b'"pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": nu'
            b'll}, {"name": "stickied", "field_name": "stickied", "pandas_type'
            b'": "bool", "numpy_type": "bool", "metadata": null}, {"name": "cr'
            b'eated_time", "field_name": "created_time", "pandas_type": "unico'
            b'de", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": null}], "creator": {"li'
            b'brary": "pyarrow", "version": "0.14.0"}, "pandas_version": "0.25'
            b'.0"}'}
```

For parquet 129 file, it seems to generate a new column "**index_level_0**".
Explicitly supplying dtypes would not cure this problem. How can I solve this?

Comment: I learned that using engine='fastparquet' does not make this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Per [@matthew-son](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127394/dask-valueerror-schema-different#comment100775408_57127394)'s comment, setting the engine to `fastparquet` helped me get past this when moving parquet files on my server.

*Note*: you may need to install `fastparquet` and `python-snappy` to get this to work

```sh
pip install fastparquet python-snappy
```

And then in Python:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet('*.parquet', engine='fastparquet')

# continue using dask / pandas
```

Comment: I had to install snappy library on my mac to the above to make it finally work. `brew install snappy`